# convert rows to column and access values for mathematical operation python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I got the following data as output:

```
my_list = [-1.65021 kcal mol-1, -0.0610136 kcal mol-1, -0.00590799 kcal mol-1, -0.0628508 kcal mol-1, -0.00977042 kcal mol-1, -0.0110948 kcal mol-1, -0.0149813 kcal mol-1, 0.00487253 kcal mol-1, 0.0173691 kcal mol-1]
```

I want to see each entry like `-1.65021 kcal mol-1`, in each row of one column. e.g:

```
-1.65021 kcal mol-1,
-0.0610136 kcal mol-1
-0.00590799 kcal mol-1
```

Then I want to access all numbers; I'm not interested in the units at this point. I want to use the values for mathematical operations.

I tried this way but it's not working:

```
y = str(my_list)
x = y.split()
z = float(x)
```

Comment: This my_list list is wrong, python would immediately throw a SyntaxError. It should have quotes for each item of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['-1.65021 kcal mol-1', '-0.0610136 kcal mol-1', '-0.00590799 kcal mol-1', '-0.0628508 kcal mol-1', '-0.00977042 kcal mol-1', '-0.0110948 kcal mol-1', '-0.0149813 kcal mol-1', '0.00487253 kcal mol-1', '0.0173691 kcal mol-1']
```

You can use a list comprehension as follows: `split` each item, index the first element `[0]` and convert to `float`.

```
[float(i.split()[0]) for i in my_list]
```

Output

```
[-1.65021, -0.0610136, -0.00590799, -0.0628508, -0.00977042, -0.0110948, -0.0149813, 0.00487253, 0.0173691]
```

Comment: do I need to write for loop again ?

Comment: Assign the list comprehension to a variable and then you can loop over that list and perform any calculations you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you also can do is create a generator which can be reused later in your code.

Generators have less memory impact than list comprehensions, if the number of items is big.

```
    my_list = [
    '-1.65021 kcal mol-1',
    '-0.0610136 kcal mol-1',
    '-0.00590799 kcal mol-1',
    '-0.0628508 kcal mol-1',
    '-0.00977042 kcal mol-1',
    '-0.0110948 kcal mol-1',
    '-0.0149813 kcal mol-1',
    '0.00487253 kcal mol-1',
    '0.0173691 kcal mol-1'
]

def generator(x):
    for item in x:
        yield float(item.split()[0])


my_sum = sum(generator(my_list))
my_min = min(generator(my_list))
my_max = max(generator(my_list))

print(my_sum)
print(my_min)
print(my_max)
```

Output:

```
-1.79358728
-1.65021
0.0173691
```

Edit:

If you need to print the output of a generator, you must first convert it to a tuple or a list

```
print(list(generator(my_list)))
print(tuple(generator(my_list)))
```

Output:

```
[-1.65021, -0.0610136, -0.00590799, -0.0628508, -0.00977042, -0.0110948, -0.0149813, 0.00487253, 0.0173691]
(-1.65021, -0.0610136, -0.00590799, -0.0628508, -0.00977042, -0.0110948, -0.0149813, 0.00487253, 0.0173691)
```

Comment: How I can print my list ? print(generator(my_list)) ?